# Debug Node.js & Express App - Intermittently using 100% CPU

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, firebase

I'm developing an app using NGinx + Node.js + Express + Firebase that simply takes input from a mobile app and stores it to Firebase, optionally uploading files to S3.

In its simplest terms, the "create" function does this

- Validates input
- Formats the input Checks if there is a file uploaded
  (via the `multer` plugin) and stores it
- If there was a file, upload
  to Amazon S3 and delete the source file (it's important to note I was
  encountering this issue before the inclusion of S3).
- Create the item
  by pushing into the items reference on Firebase
- Create the item for
  the user by pushing into the user_items reference on Firebase.

There are a few other functions that I have implemented as an API.

**My trouble is coming from an intermittent spike in CPU usage**, which is causing the nginx server to report a gateway timeout from the Node.js application.

Sometimes the server will fall over when performing authentication against a MongoDB instance, other times it will fall over when I'm recieving the input from the Mobile app. There doesn't seem to be any consistency between when it falls over. Sometimes it works fine for 15+ various requests (upload/login/list, etc), but sometimes it will fall over after just one request.

I have added error checking in the form of:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
});
```

Which will throw errors if I mistype a variable for example, but when the server crashes there are no exceptions thrown. Similarly checking my logs shows me nothing. I've tried profiling the application but the output doesn't make any sense at all to me. It doesn't point to a function or plugin in particular.

I appreciate this is a long winded problem but I'd really appreciate it if you could point me in a direction for debugging this issue, it's causing me such a headache!

Comment: [Bugger](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bugger) might help. You use Chrome dev tools to access it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but `bugger` won't start on my server, throwing an ECONNREFUSED even though I'm root. Have looked at node-inspector but it doesn't give me any visibility over the network tab, which I think would be crucial to understand if it's any external call that's causing it.

Comment: Have you tried using something like New Relic to help check your app?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've installed it but New Relic doesn't seem to be returning much data of use. I'll keep it installed just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer was to do with the fact that my Express app was reusing one Firebase connection for every request, and for some reason this was causing the server to lock up.

My solution was to create some basic middleware that provides a new reference to the Firebase on each API request, see below:

```
var Middleware = {

    /*
     * Initialise Firebase Refs per connection
     */
    initFireBase: function(req, res, next) {

        console.log('Intialising Firebase for user');

        // We need a authToken
        var authToken = req.param('authToken');

        // Validate the auth token
        if(!authToken || authToken.length === 0) {
            return res.send(500, {code: 'INVALID_TOKEN', message: 'You must supply an authToken to this method.'});
        }
        else {

            // Attempt to parse the auth token
            try {
                var decodedToken = JWTSimple.decode(authToken, serverToken);
            }
            catch(e) {
                return res.send(500, {code: 'INVALID_TOKEN', message: 'Supplied token was not recognised.'});
            }

            // Bail out if the token is invalid
            if(!decodedToken) {
                return res.send(500, {code: 'INVALID_TOKEN', message: 'Supplied token was not recognised.'});
            }

            // Otherwise send the decoded token with the request
            else {
                req.auth = decodedToken.d;
            }

        }

        // Create a root reference
        var rootRef = new Firebase('my firebase url');

        // Apply the references to each request
        req.refs = {
            root: rootRef,
            user: rootRef.child('users'),
            inbox: rootRef.child('inbox')
        };

        // Carry on to the calling function
        next();

    }

};
```

I then simply call this middleware on my routes:

```
/*
 * Create a post
 */
router.all('/createPost', Middleware.initFireBase, function(req, res) {

  var refs = req.refs;
  refs.inbox.push({}) // etc

....
```

This middleware will soon be extended to provide `Firebase.auth()` on the connection to ensure that any API call made with a valid authToken would be signed to the user on Firebase's side. However for development this is acceptable.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in the Firebase library. What version are you using?

I've been having a very similar issue that has had me frustrated for days. Node.js + Express + Firebase on Heroku. Process will run for a seemingly random time then I start getting timeout errors from Heroku without the process ever actually crashing or showing an error. Higher load doesn't seem to make it happen sooner.

I just updated from Firebase 1.0.14 to latest 1.0.19 and I think it may have fixed the problem for me. Process has been up for 2 hours now where it would only last for 5-30 min previously. More testing to do, but thought I'd share my in-progress results in case they were helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I have been using Firebase 1.0.19 for development - but I have rebuilt the app using some methods that I'll detail in my answer, and it hasn't crashed yet (24h +)